# date conversion

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, date-arithmetic

I need to get todays date - last date +1 as a count of days

For example I am having a date value as 40641 as last_arrear_date.
I need to get a due date count as of todays date
ie TODAYS DATE minus LAST_ARREAR_DATE + 1.
I want to get extract the count from PL/SQL.

How I will get that count?

Comment: What database are you using? The date functions are not in the standard, so they differ for each SQL dialect.

Comment: i m using pl sql developer...                                                  to_char(to_date((Strt_Date + 2415020) ,'J'),'DD-MON-YYYY') Strt_Date...this is hw i will get converted date from binary to DD-MON-YYY format... but here i  need the  count of days

Comment: pl/sql developer is not the database, it's one of the interfaces to an Oracle database. (so it does identify the database :-) )

Comment: PL/SQL Developer is a tool, not a database. But obviously you're using Oracle. Please add this as a tag to your question.

Comment: as Sais Codo below, you can simply subtract two dates and you will get the difference in days, but  looking at your example : `to_char(to_date((Strt_Date + 2415020) ,'J'),'DD-MON-YYYY')` if im not wrong, the column Strt_Date is a Number that you add to a julian date `2415020` which is the `31/12/1899`, could you give more details about the structure ect... ?

Comment: 40641 - what sort of date is that?

Comment: @Sara - time to start rewarding some answers, ok?

Answer (score 4):

You can simply subtract two dates:

```
SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE) - LAST_ARREAR_DATE + 1 AS DAY_COUNT FROM DUAL;
```